# How do I make Gnome's "Login keyring" unlock on a regular password login in Fedora?

Tags: fedora, gnome-keyring

My login keyring started asking a password after login. I do not use auto-login, I use a regular login with a password. I tried to re-create a keyring, and might made things worse. The passwords for my account and for the keyring are the same.

Where do I start, if I want to troubleshoot this?

Maybe I need to mention it, but it stopped unlocking after I enabled all the secure boot things on the motherboard to install windows besides fedora. Maybe it has to do something with my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you change to a different password? It will only automatically unlock if you have the same password to the keyring as your account (it is also case-sensitive I believe).

To change the keyring's password, open the gnome-keyring app and click back if you are not on the main menu. Right click on the first item (probably called "Login", my system language is not English) and select change password. Type in the old password, and now you can create a new one.

Comment: I haven't. I tried re-creating the keyring, but the password to the new default keyring is the same as my account's password.

By the way, initially, it stopped unlocking without me changing anything about keyrings at all. It stopped working right after I enabled secure boot on the motherboard. Idk, if these two fact are connected or not.